# How to remove from and Entity Framework -> WCF -> WPF solution

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf

I'm currently implementing a client server (non web) application that I have inherited and want to remove the `WCF` aspects from.

I was told that this is what I need to do with management that has a much greater understanding of what needs doing. The `WPF` GUI app somehow uses `WCF` to be bound to controls in my `WPF` client GUI application  `WCF` for the communication between client and server. I've heard that using `WCF` we're bound to use some Microsoft technology at the client side, and can't easily replace this with "anything" - at least with the default SOAP implementation of `WPF`.

I found some answers to these questions with a question / answer from 6 years ago and am asking again since 6 years is a long time for change and something else I do not know about here might be relevant.

I know I want to have my `WPF` based controls be as directly connected to `Entity framework`. In the meantime, I am educating myself so as to not be such a newbie to all of this.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Just use [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) works well with `Entity Framework`

Comment: Thanks very much. Is web API the only option? I ask because whatever I use I am totally new to and would like to know other options if there are any. I have the original solution set and there is currently an Entity Frame work  bunch of files ( .edmx .edmx.sql .svc, .svc.cs) I do not see where the WCF technology plugs into the ef model or how the GUI app makes use of what the WCF provides which is the place I assume I would want to "use web API" and change the bindings in my controls to use EF objects and abandon altogether WCF. Thanks very much again. Am gonna now go study web API, thank you

Comment: Its difficult to say as your question is quite broad. I would suggest breaking your problem here down into different questions and posting them with your code. The WPF app will likely call the WCF service at some point so I would start there eg `ServiceReference` or `HttpWebRequest`

Comment: I would like to eliminate the existing WCF Data service dll and have the WPF app and its controls to be "directly" connected to the database using entity framework model elements. Assuming WEB API is an option to accomplish this, is it the only one? Thanks again